# the length of rows and index is same but still face the problem

Tags: python, valueerror

[1][value error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjuOi.png)[image: value error]

I tried what I know but still it gives me headache can anyone solve this?

Comment: # there are three continues variables in this data set 'year','eingineV' and 'Mileage' lets find variance inflation factor
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor
variables = data_cleaned[['Mileage','EngineV','Year']]

Comment: Please share your code not screenshot